# Google Glass : Maximal number of characters in a Card?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

What is the maximal number of character that we can put into a Card ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the text size will resize automatically depending upon the number of characters.

Refer to this link: [Google Mirror API Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground)